# UITableView scrollToRow no longer works on iOS 11 right after adding a new row

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I've noticed a weird UITableView behaviour which only seems to occur on iOS 11 devices.

Right after inserting a new row (changing data source and then calling reloadData, `UITableView` won't scroll to that row when calling `scrollToRow` or `scrollToBottom()` method.

When doing the some thing on iOS 10 or earlier version, it works perfectly and UITable scrolls like it's supposed to.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the `updateRowAtIndexPath(oldLastRowIndexPath)` method?

Comment: @FahriAzimov just edited my original question and added the function. Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen all the time? I mean, when your old last cell is visible, or when it's not?

Comment: Highly recommend that you switch to the `UICollectionView`. I was having the same problems like you, after switching to `UICollectionView` those problems are gone. `UICollectionView` seems to be much more smooth on insert, delete, move, and scrolling operations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
});
```

Adding a small delay is working in my case.

Comment: Same thing ended up working for me in the end, I just forgot to post my answer, so I'll just accept yours :) But yeah, for some reason adding delay works...

Comment: Did you file a radar?

Comment: Is there a bug for this issue?

Comment: But, another possible way to solve the trouble may be, assign the estimatedRowHeight and  estimatedSectionHeaderHeight with 0. it can prevent iOS from automatically adjust size and position of tableview.

Answer (score 2):

[Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46424935/3659227) in **Swift 4** syntax

```
let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
                    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)
                }
```

Comment: Why 1 second? Seems like a long time, where in most cases you might originally expected this to be "instant" or at least near-instant.

Comment: Anyway, thanks. I changed `.seconds(1)` to `.milliseconds(1)` and things seem to work so far.

Comment: I'm back and I suspect this is actually a kind of dangerous thing to do. You probably want to make sure that the row and section specified by the indexpath still exist once the waiting time is over. If the row/section exceeds available rows/sections (they might be removed by some other process), scrollToRow will crash.

Comment: Agreed, it would be wise to check the existence of that specific row and section first.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the situation I encountered applies to this question, but I also had a situation where `UITableView.scrollTo...` started misbehaving from iOS 11.

In my case, I was calling `UITableView.reload...` and `UITableView.scrollTo...` consecutively. And what it turned out is that the order matters.

This works :

```
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

This doesn't :

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
tableView.reloadData()
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

Just `DispatchQueue.main.async` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Are you calling `scrollToRow()` in viewDidAppear?

Moving the function call from `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidAppear` worked for me.

Comment: This causes a noticeable jump in my app (iOS12)