# UITableView scrollToRow does not work in ios 11, 13

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, ios11

I have a scenario where I need to scroll the tableview till a particular row. I am using this code

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: scrollPosition, animated: animated)
```

This used to work perfectly, but lately, users with iOS 11 have reported that this doesn't work. And I've checked myself. It just doesn't scroll.

I looked up online and found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075517/uitableview-scrolltorow-no-longer-works-on-ios-11-right-after-adding-a-new-row)

The accepted answer states that adding a small delay to the scroll code does the trick. Which is true but only for 6s or below devices running iOS11. It doesn't work with 7plus.

Anybody got an idea what needs to be done?

Comment: Just for checking purposes, what if you'd increase the time of the delaying? will it work?

Comment: @dasdom Did you reply to a wrong thread?

Comment: @AhmadF Tried increasing the delay till 1 whole second. Doesn't work on 7plus.

Comment: @PrateekChoudhary Jack deleted his comment.

Comment: What context are you calling the code from?

Comment: @Vlad I have added a method to the NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow notification. Then the scroll code is called in that method.

Comment: Have you tried changing the value of `scrollPosition`?  I am using `.bottom` and it is working on iPhone 8 Plus.

Comment: Can't remember if it's since iOS 10 or 11, but UIKit calls are now **required** to happen on the main thread (queue). Are you calling `scrollToRow(:_at:animated:)` from within some sort of _completion handler_?